# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc) in TableView ScrollToRow

Tags: swift, uikit

I am creating a chat where the following code is found:

```
    @objc
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if textInputWrapperBottomConstraints.constant == 0 {
                textInputWrapperBottomConstraints.constant += keyboardSize.height
                
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false, block: {_ in
                    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: self.messages.count-1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
                })
                
            }
        }
    }
```

It gives me the following error on the line:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc)
  self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: self.messages.count-1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

I can't find the reason for the failure

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an index out of bounds exception. If `self.messages.count` == 0, you would end up with an `IndexPath.row` of -1 which is invalid and hence the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

You could check the indices of the array before you do it like so:

```
let proposedRow: Int = self.messages.count - 1
guard proposedRow > 0 else { return }
guard self.messages.indices.contains(proposedRow) else { return }
guard self.tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) > proposedRow else { return }
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: proposedRow, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved it that way. 
The error was that I wanted to access position -1

Comment: No probs, as a rule of thumb with arrays, they are zero indexed, meaning that the first index is always zero and you can never have an index lower than zero.